# php find 3 consecutive dates in array

Tags: php

i have this code to find 3 consecutive dates in an array but i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

php code:

```
$datesarray = array('2012-10-01', '2012-10-03', '2012-10-04', '2012-10-05', '2012-10-08', '2012-10-09');

    $count = 0;
    $result = "Nothing found";

        foreach ($datesarray as $value) {
            if(strtotime($datesarray[$count]) - strtotime($datesarray[$count-1]) - strtotime($datesarray[$count-2]) == -1349150400) {
                $result = "3 Consecutive dates found";
            }
        $count++; 
        }  

    echo "Result: $result";
```

Comment: Wrong forum. Should be in code review instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script gives me:

```
Result: Nothing found
```

but there are 3 consecutive dates

I've changed the script:

```
<?php

$datesarray = array('2012-10-01', '2012-10-03', '2012-10-04', '2012-10-05', '2012-10-08', '2012-10-09');

$result = "Nothing found";


$diff = strtotime('2014-05-07') - strtotime('2014-05-06');

for ($i=2, $c=count($datesarray); $i<$c; ++$i) {
    if (strtotime($datesarray[$i-1]) - strtotime($datesarray[$i-2]) == $diff &&
        strtotime($datesarray[$i]) - strtotime($datesarray[$i-2]) == $diff * 2) {
            $result = "3 Consecutive dates found";                
            break;
    }

}
echo "Result: $result";
```

and the result is

```
Result: 3 Consecutive dates found
```

Is this what you expected?

Comment: mine shows Result: 3 Consecutive dates found... not sure why you got Nothing found with my code....

Comment: I have also warning in your script because in your foreach you check also not existing elements. On my PC in your script I have values 1349042400, 172800, -1348956000, -1349128800, -1349042400, -1349301600 in comparison